# How i can embed Outlook Web App into my site?

Tags: javascript, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, outlook

I want to embed Outlook Web App into my site. Show Calendar, mail, people screens directly on pages of my site. I tried to do it via iFrame, but it is forbidden. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Have you seen this [Outlook Integration](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rambab/outlookintegration10282006032802am/outlookintegration.aspx)

Comment: I think it it not that i mean. I don't want to implement outlook portal from scratches. I just want to show default Outlook Web Application on page of my site.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to common belief, this is achievable.

There are more details in my blogpost (http://blog.degree.no/2013/06/owa-in-iframe-yes-its-possible/) but here's the code needed. If you run it in "light mode" (flag = 1) there are less issues and it works cross domain, but if you run it within the same domain (e.g. website running on yourdomain.com and your exchange server is running on mail.yourdomain.com) it works fine for "full mode" (flag = 0) as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<script>
    function LoginToOWA(server, domain, username, password) {


        var url = "https://" + server + "/owa/auth/owaauth.dll";
        // flags 0 = full version, flags 1 = light weight mode
        var p = { destination: 'https://' + server + '/exchange', flags: '1', forcedownlevel: '0', trusted: '0', isutf8: '1', username: domain + '\\' + username, password: password };


        var myForm = document.createElement("form");
        myForm.method = "post";
        myForm.action = url;

        for (var k in p) {

            var myInput = document.createElement("input");
            myInput.setAttribute("name", k);
            myInput.setAttribute("value", p[k]);
            myForm.appendChild(myInput);
        }


        document.body.appendChild(myForm);
        myForm.submit();
        document.body.removeChild(myForm);
    }
</script>


<body onload="javascript:LoginToOWA('mail.someserver.com','yourdomain','yourusername@someserver.com','yourpassword');">
    <img src="../../gfx/loadingAnim.gif" /> Please wait while your inbox is loading... 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to do that, but received 404 (Not found) error from server.

Comment: What's the URL to your OWA? You did replace the dummy settings ("mail.someserver.com", "yourdomain" etc) with your own, obviosuly? :)

Comment: Yes, i used settings for my email

Comment: Sounds like the generated URL pointing to your mailserver isn't correct. Debug the script, find out what the actual output is. Are you able to get the OWA login when you type in "https://mail.yourserver.com]owa"?

Comment: I am researching on this same topic - whether its possible to embed office 365 outlook in a third party web application. I get errors stating that its not possible to do so. The link in the above post isn't working. From the above discussion I don't follow why the url would be different. It is the standard url - http://outlook.office365.com. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of OWA are you having? I have done this before for our company's intranet on OWA-2003. Just point your iframe to the webpart url like this:

```
http://server/exchange/user/inbox/?cmd=contents&view=Two-Line%20View&theme=4
```

This will work only if your main website uses Windows Integrated Authentication. You have to replace "user" with the logged in username using ASP.Net server-side code.

Search MS KB articles for the webpart parameters. You can show inbox, calendar etc.

Comment: I'm just trying to use this html:<iframe src="https://pod51050.outlook.com/owa/" width="1024" height="800">
</iframe>

Comment: can you add link to this MS KB articles?

Comment: Ok. That helped. I see that this link goes to login.live.com for authentication. The login.live.com site implements the http header `X-Frame-Options` set to "deny". There is nothing you can or should do.

Comment: @Abhitalks - I am researching on this same topic - whether its possible to embed office 365 outlook in a third party web application. I get the same errors. Does that conclude that embedding outlook isn't possible or there are other options that could be tried? Also are there any references that say that office 365 apps were designed with the principle of not being able to embed them anywhere? That would make the point strong.

Comment: @AndyDufresne: When I wrote this answer, this was for Exchange 2003 on-premise. This technique worked and was supported and documented by Microsoft. They called it OWA web parts. However, from Exchange 2013 (CU2) onwards they started inserting  X-Frame-Options header to protect against click-jacking. This applied to O365 as well. As of now the security restrictions are higher than ever and rightly so because O365 is a public cloud. (I think you can still override X-Frame on-premise, but it is not advisable). For O365, the recommended method is to write code using APIs, EWS/Graph.

Comment: @AndyDufresne: Here is the authoritative reference that you asked for: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2015/05/14/owa-customization-and-development. Please note the paragraph which says this clearly: *"... note that OWA web parts from a shared Exchange Online server cannot be used in an IFRAME because all the needed settings to override click-jacking cannot be set ....If you want to use OWA Web Parts in an IFRAME then you need to use a dedicated Exchange Online server or an on premise server".*